# Javascript evaluation error in LESS file

Tags: javascript, less

I have the follwoing code in less file:

```
@winheight: unit(`document.documentElement.clientHeight`, px);
```

and I want to call that variable in:

```
.test {
    height: ~"@{winheight}";
}
```

But I still get an error at variable `@winheight`:

> LESS: JavaScript evaluation error: 'TypeError:
>   'document.documentElement.clientHeight' is null or not an object'

How to fix this? Where is my mistake ?

Comment: You expect the LESS compiler to know what the screenheight of your future visitors is going to be?

Comment: I expect to return current client's document height...

Comment: Seems to work fine @ lesstester.com mate.

Comment: I have this error in VS2012 with Web Essentials installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.documentElement.clientHeight` can only exists when running less.js, in browser see: http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser.

In all other situations your Less code will be compiled into **static** CSS code.